# Subquery in MySql group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query:

```
SELECT round(addTime/qty, 0) AS col1,
       sum(qty) AS col2,
       cId AS Id
FROM MyTable
WHERE qty > 0
GROUP BY round(addTime/qty, 0), cId
ORDER BY round(addTime/qty, 0)
```

But I have to replace addTime with a

```
SUM(CASE WHEN qty = 1 THEN 1 ELSE DATEDIFF(second,startTime,endTime) END)/qty, 0)
```

And when I do this:

```
SELECT round(SUM(case when qty = 1 then 1 else DATEDIFF(second,startTime,endTime) end)/qty, 0) AS col1,
sum(qty) AS col2,
cId
FROM MyTable
WHERE qty > 0
GROUP BY round(SUM(case when qty = 1 then 1 else
DATEDIFF(second,startTime,endTime) end)/qty, 0)/qty, 0), cId
ORDER BY round(SUM(case when qty = 1 then 1 else DATEDIFF(second,startTime,endTime) end)/qty, 0)/qty, 0)
```

I get

```
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.
```

My idea was that I can use that new query as variable and then use it where I need but then I ran into trouble with MySql syntax.

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        round(SUM(case when qty = 1 then 1 else DATEDIFF(second, startTime,endTime) end)/qty, 0) AS col1, 
        sum(qty) AS col2, 
        cId
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE qty > 0
) AS t
GROUP BY t.col1, t.cId
ORDER BY t.col1
```

Also I'm not sure, but your `DIFFTIME` function if different from MySQL `DIFFTIME`.

Comment: Good answer but it returns me an error saying that I need to use qty in GROUP BY also. "Column 'qty' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." Although I did use GROUP BY t1.col1 in GROUP BY

Comment: @RVstack are you sure that you are using MySQL?

Comment: Yes. And I got it to work. I had a type in my query. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a sub query in the from clause:

Select * from (select round(...) as col1 from MyTable) as tmp where ... Group By tmp.col1

[Subqueries in from clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)